# Data recovery tool for external hard-disk

Tags: windows, hard-disk, data-recovery

My external hard drive (not SSD) had a "soft failure", meaning that the mechanics seem to be fine, but some files got errouneously deleted from file system after a `chkdsk` fix. I know the list of files that got deleted. Partition is NTFS, I'm using Windows 10 x64.

I've tried a Deep Scan with Recuva, finding 10% of those files.
Then I tried EaseUS Data Recovery, this time the results were a lot more, like an 80% of the total.

So now I'm wondering if there is another software that can recover even more files. before purchase the full version and proceed with real recovery.
I've heard about Disk Drill, but I didn't find an exhaustive benchmark of all of these alternatives. I would like to use this drive as least as possible in testing other tools.

Comment: You should give the free tools PhotoRec and TestDisk a try. No guarantees – but no fee involved either.

Comment: Thanks, for what I've tried so far, I'm considering paid recovery software better than freeware (see Recuva vs EaseUS). I can give TestDisk a try anyway, but is there some reviews/benchmark of it around the web?

Comment: I don't know of any benchmarks. It's just what I used when I needed some recovery tool, and it worked OK for me. So I thought while waiting for good answers, you might wish to check. I can't tell how good it fits your needs, hence I just wrote a comment and not an answer ;)

Comment: @TheUnexpected: What was your result? Did you try it?

Comment: I ended up using paid EaseUS. PhotoRec was quite more complex to use and I didn't see any improvement in number of recovered files.

Comment: For other readers: I tried EaseUS as well, but that software seems to identify VMWare hard disks or VHD hard disks as partitions as well. Restoring those partitions on top of the real partitions is certainly not a good idea.